# add/show layer(group) on click [leaflet]

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am a beginner in leaflet.

Basically, I have a circle. I would like to show another circle when clicked on this circle. And hide it again when clicked for the second time. How is that possible?

```
 //the circle which will haven on click event
    var circle1 = L.circle([44.6663888888889, 6.775],{radius: 150, color:'white',weight:.5, opacity:1,fillColor: '#ff9900',fillOpacity:1});

//the circle to be added when one click on circle 1
    var circle2 = L.circle([44.6502777777778, 6.79333333333333], {radius: 150, color:'white',weight:.5, opacity:1,fillColor: '#008000',fillOpacity:1});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a click event to `circle1`, and then add the logic to add or remove `circle2`:

```
//the circle which will haven on click event
var circle1 = L.circle([44.6663888888889, 6.775], { radius: 150, color: 'white', weight: .5, opacity: 1, fillColor: '#ff9900', fillOpacity: 1 });

//the circle to be added when one click on circle 1
var circle2 = L.circle([44.6502777777778, 6.79333333333333], { radius: 150, color: 'white', weight: .5, opacity: 1, fillColor: '#008000', fillOpacity: 1 });

circle1.addTo(map);

circle1.on("click", function (e) {

    //check to see if the circle is already on the map
    //and add/remove as needed

    if (map.hasLayer(circle2)) {
        circle2.remove(map);
    } else {
        circle2.addTo(map);
    }

});
```